# Nexus 5 updated to 5.0.1 using OTA but is now stuck at boot animation for more than 10 minutes

Tags: updates, nexus-5, boot-animation

Yesterday I've bought my first Nexus phone.

I've tried updating it to Android 5.0.1 through standard procedure (download -> update from Settings), but now it is booting (boot animation is playing) for 10 minutes already. Any idea what could that be and what should I do to the phone to get back to normal working Android?

Answer (score 1):

On some phones it can take very long, even to half an hour, so  try to wait a little more.

If that does not help you should try to do a factory reset and wipe `/cache` & `/dalvik` partition (from Recovery, if you have access to it). Usually this procedure would solve the issue: stuck on boot animation/reboot loops.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't factory reset already be wiping /cache and /dalvik-cache?

Comment: I'm not totally sure. It usually depends on recovery, on mine device and recovery I know that I always had to manually format `/dalvik`, but not remember for `/cache`.